# Were photographs or optical measurements of orbital craft from the ground ever used during early crewed spaceflight missions?

Tags: history, photography, tracking, visibility-of-spacecraft, project-mercury

The lengthy and interesting blogpost [Baker-Nunn Camera, Island Lagoon](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/other_stations/island_lagoon/baker-nunn.html) on Colin Mackellar's Honeysuckle Creek website includes a photo of "Gemini 10 (with John Young and Mike Collins onboard) and the Gemini 8 Agena Target Vehicle... prior to rendezvous" from "Woomera, 21.07.1966, 0523 local time".

Since photographic plates take time to expose, remove, develop, measure, and then analyze, these are great for post-mission analysis but not ideal for providing mission-critical data during the mission itself. But "not ideal" from a 2021 perspective doesn't mean "wasn't used" in 1965.

**Question:** Where photographs or optical measurements of *orbital* craft from the ground ever used *during* early *crewed* spaceflight missions?

**note 1:** This is not at all limited to Project Mercury or NASA! I just ran across the post and it inspired this question.

**note 2:** "orbital" means not during launch or reentry, or basically not within the atmosphere, "during" means not afterward in post-mission analysis, "crewed" means astronauts on board; not tracking the enemy's spy satellites for example.

---

[image: cropped and annotated Gemini 10 (with John Young and Mike Collins onboard) and the Gemini 8 Agena Target Vehicle]

[image: Gemini 10 (with John Young and Mike Collins onboard) and the Gemini 8 Agena Target Vehicle]

> Three years to the day before the first manned lunar landing, this photo of Gemini 10 (with John Young and Mike Collins onboard) and the Gemini 8 Agena Target Vehicle was taken from Woomera by the Baker-Nunn tracking camera.
>
> Photo and notes by Ed von Renouard. Ed writes:
>
> “Woomera, 21.07.1966, 0523 local time.
>
> Gemini 10 and Agena prior to rendezvous, Gemini below and to the right, separation appr. 2 miles, slant range appr. 700 miles.
>
> The Baker-Nunn Camera was tracking at appr. twice the rate of the two vehicles in order to overtake and photograph them (shortly after this exposure, they were lost below the horizon).
>
> The four stars [click image for the full picture] are small stars in Taurus.”
>
> Key. Thanks to Ed von Renouard, via Hamish Lindsay. Scan by Colin Mackellar.

Answer (score 4):

The [Baker Nunn camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_camera#Baker%E2%80%93Nunn) used a very special film format, ten inches of 55 mm wide [cinemascope film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CinemaScope#CinemaScope_55), (254 mm by about 46 mm.)

[image]

[image]

From http://bollerandchivens.com/?p=561

So photographic plates or sheets of instant film could not be used, only flexible film on a roll.

The Baker-Nunn Satellite Tracking Stations  like those at Hawaii were equipped with a darkroom, so the films could be developed onsite.

The used black and white film was simple to develop, a developer, a stop bath and a fixation bath. After these the film was rinsed with water and dried. Astronomers using similar telescopes were used to develop

To speed up development, incomplete fixation and rinsing was possible. After the images were measured, the fixation and rinsing could be completed to achieve images archivable for decades.

So a rapid development was possible in about 10 to 15 minutes.

[image]

From http://bollerandchivens.com/?p=561

The image of Gemini 10 and Agena was taken at 21.07. 0523 local time, that is 20.07 1957 UTC. Undocking was done at 20.07. 1900 UTC.
The image was taken after undocking, it could not be used for preparation of docking.

So the notes from Woomera *Gemini 10 and Agena prior to rendezvous* seem to be wrong, either the time 0523 is wrong or prior to rendezvous.

The optical measurements during a manned mission could only be used for validation of electronic orbit measurements when done at least an hour in advance to the next orbital maneuver.

Comment: Wow this is really interesting, thank you for the update and thorough descriptions!

Answer (score 2):

From *Fundamentals of SPACE GEODESY* book, 1976 http://epizodsspace.airbase.ru/bibl/krasnorylov/osnovy/krasnorylov-osnovy-76%20.pdf

page 105 § 2. Classification of observation methods for artificial earth satellites.

> Простейшим телескопом, применявшимся для наблюдений спутников в СССР при первых их запусках, являлась астрономическая трубка АТ-1. Аналогичные телескопы применялись в США. Точность наблюдений такой аппаратурой не превышала О, 1-0,3s по времени и 0,2-0,3 градусов по положению.
>
> The simplest telescope used to observe satellites in the USSR during their first launches was the AT-1 astronomical tube. Similar telescopes have been used in the United States. The accuracy of observations with such equipment did not exceed 0, 1-0.3s in time and 0.2-0.30 deg. in position.
>
> Наиболее пригодным для визуальных наблюдений является инструмент типа кинотеодолит, имеющий трубы-искатели и электромеханический привод, что позволяет отслеживать движение спутника и наблюдать его в течение одного прохождения многократно. Отсчеты кругов и поле зрения при этом фотографируются. Примерам подобного инструмента является кинотеодолит Аскания (рис. 27).
>
> The most suitable for visual observation is a cinetheodolite-type instrument with search tubes and an electromechanical drive, which makes it possible to track the satellite's movement and observe it repeatedly during one passage. The counts of the circles and the field of view are photographed. An example of such a tool is the Askania cinetheodolite (Fig. 27).

[image]

> § 3. Фотографические наблюдения спутников
>
> Наиболее широкое распространение получили фотографические наблюдения
> ИСЗ , так как долгое время ни один другой метод не мог с ними
> конкурировать по точности. Однако бурное развитие сначала
> допплеровских, а затем лазерных наблюдений отодвигает эти методы по
> точности на второе место.
>
> § 3. Photographic observations of satellites
> The most widespread are photographic observations of satellites, since for a long time no other method could compete with them in accuracy. However, the rapid development of first Doppler observations and then laser observations pushes these methods to second place in accuracy.
>
> Фотографические наблюдения документальны, позволяют в случае необходимости многократно повторять измерения. Положения ИСЗ на снимке определяются путем привязки к опорным звездам в системе некоторого звездного каталога. Широкому применению фотографического метода в немалой степени способствовал почти полувековой опыт, накопленный астрономами в области теории и практики фотографической астрометрии.

> Вместе с тем отмеченные выше особенности наблюдений ИСЗ потребовали внесения в классические методы и приёмы фотографической астрометрии существенных корректив.
> Эти коррективы затронули аппаратурные вопросы, методику наблюдений, приемы обработки и т. д.

> Photographic observations are documentary, they allow, if necessary, to repeat measurements many times. The satellite positions in the image are determined by reference to the reference stars in the system of a certain star catalog. The widespread use of the photographic method was greatly facilitated by the nearly half-century experience accumulated by astronomers in the field of the theory and practice of photographic astrometry.

> At the same time, the aforementioned features of AES observations required significant adjustments to the classical methods and techniques of photographic astrometry.
> These adjustments affected hardware issues, observation techniques, processing techniques, etc.

> Согласно расчетам, выполненным в Смитсоновский астрофизической обсерватории (SAO) США, камера для наблюдения спутников не должна иметь параметры меньше следующих:
> F=400 мм, D= 100 мм, 2σ=5 * 10° (10°- вдоль следа ИСЗ). Предпочтительнее однако, если F= 1000 мм, D= 150-200 мм.

> According to calculations carried out at the Smithsonian Astrophysical Observatory (SAO), USA, the camera for observing satellites should not have parameters less than the following:
> F = 400 mm, D = 100 mm, 2σ = 5 * 10 ° (10 ° - along the satellite track). However, it is preferable if F = 1000 mm, D = 150-200 mm.

> Для фотографирования использовались и используются как модифицированные камеры, в первоначальном варианте применявшиеся для других целей (НАФА-3с/25, Вильд ВС-4 и т. д.),
> так и специально созданные спутниковые камеры (Бейкера Наина, АФУ-75, ВАУ, SBG и т. д.).

> For photographing, we used and are used as modified cameras, originally used for other purposes (NAFA-3s/25, Wild-BC-4, etc.), and specially designed satellite cameras (Baker Nunn, AFU-75, VAU, SBG, etc.)

[image]

> Все камеры, используемые для наблюдений спутников, можно разделить на две группы. Камеры одной из этих групп не отслеживают движение спутника. Они могут иметь азимутальную или экваториальную монтировку. В последнем случае камера может отслеживать суточное движение звезд, что позволяет получать на снимке более слабые звезды. Вторую группу образуют следящие камеры. Эти камеры имеют трехосную или четырехосную монтировку. Как правило, неследящие камеры более портативные и дешевые. Иногда фотографические камеры для наблюдений спутников делят на три группы: азимутальные (неподвижные), экваториальные (звездные) и следящие.

> All cameras used to observe satellites can be divided into two groups. Cameras from one of these groups do not track satellite movement. They can be azimuthally or equatorially mounted. In the latter case, the camera can track the diurnal movement of the stars, which makes it possible to capture fainter stars in the image. The second group is formed by tracking cameras. These cameras have a three-axis or four-axis mount. Generally, non-tracking cameras are more portable and cheaper. Sometimes photographic cameras for observing satellites are divided into three groups: azimuthal (fixed), equatorial (stellar) and tracking.

> **Камера АФУ-75 (СССР).** Камера создана в 1965 г. на станции наблюдений ИСЗ при Рижском государственном университете М. Абеле и К. Лапушкой. Основой для ее создания послужила созданная теми же авторами в 1960 г. камера ТАФО-75.

> **Camera AFU-75 (USSR).** The camera was created in 1965 at the satellite observation station at the Riga State University by M. Abele and K. Lapushka. The basis for its creation was the TAFO-75 camera created by the same authors in 1960.

[image]
[image]

> С помощью камеры можно фотографировать активные ИСЗ, яркие пассивные ИСЗ, спутники малой яркости как быстрые, так и медленные. Для каждого случая отработаны определенные режимы работы камеры. Таким образом, АФУ-75 позволяет фотографировать спутники от 3 до 10 звездной величины, захватывая до 120° видимой дуги орбиты.

> The camera can be used to photograph active satellites, bright passive satellites, low-brightness satellites, both fast and slow. For each case, certain operating modes of the camera have been worked out. Thus, the AFU-75 makes it possible to photograph satellites from 3 to 10 magnitudes, capturing up to 120 ° of the visible arc of the orbit.

> Камеры АФУ-75 используются для наблюдений в СССР, ЧССР, НРБ, МНР, ВНР, на Кубе, в Арабская Республика Египет, Сомали и ряде других стран.

> AFU-75 cameras are used for observations in the USSR, Czechoslovakia, Bulgaria, Mongolia, Hungary, Cuba, the Arab Republic of Egypt, Somalia and a number of other countries.

> **Камера ВАУ (СССР)** предназначена для наблюдений спутников и далёких искусственных небесных тел.

> **The VAU camera (USSR)** is designed for observing satellites and distant artificial celestial bodies.

[image]

> Камера ВАУ (рис. 33) имеет трехосную экваториальную монтировку, что позволяет отслеживать движение спутника. Одна ось - часовая - направлена в полюс мира, вторая - ось склонений - позволяет ориентировать третью орбитальную ось в точку с любым склонением. Отслеживание может осуществляться со скоростями от О до 6000" в сек. При этом камера вращается вокруг орбитальной оси со скоростью видимого движения спутника, а вокруг часовой оси - со скоростью суточного вращения небесной сферы.

> The VAU camera (Fig. 33) has a three-axis equatorial mount, which allows tracking the movement of the satellite. One axis - the hour - is directed to the pole of the world, the second - the declination axis - allows you to orient the third orbital axis to a point with any declination. Tracking can be carried out at speeds from 0 to 6000 "per second. In this case, the camera rotates around the orbital axis at the speed of the apparent motion of the satellite, and around the clockwise axis - at the speed of the daily rotation of the celestial sphere.

> Монтировка камеры позволяет получить опорные звезды в виде точек в непосредственной близости от изображения спутника и тем самым ослабить влияние деформации пленки.
> В этом заключается преимущества ВАУ перед камерой Бейкера-Наина (США).

> The camera mount allows you to obtain guide stars in the form of points in the immediate vicinity of the satellite image and thereby reduce the effect of film deformation.
> This is the advantage of the VAU over the Baker Nunn camera (USA).

> Работая в разных режимах, камерой можно фотографировать слабые спутники, имеющие быстрое движение, яркие спутники, слабые медленные спутники, космические зонды и другие далекие космические объекты. Выбор режима фотографирования обусловлен яркостью и скоростью движения объекта. Камерой могут наблюдаться спутники до 12 звездной величины.

> Working in different modes, the camera can photograph faint satellites with fast movement, bright satellites, faint slow satellites, space probes and other distant space objects. The choice of the photography mode is determined by the brightness and speed of the subject. The camera can observe satellites up to magnitude 12.

> **Камера Бейкера-Наина (США)** была первой большой спутниковой следящей камерой (создана в 1956-1957 rr.). Она имеет трехосную монтировку (рис. 34 ) и может отслеживать движение спутника по дуге большого круга со скоростями от 0 до 7000" в сек. Оптическая система камеры может быть отнесена к модифицированной системе Шмидта (рис . 35). Диаметр действующего отверстия 51 см, фокусное расстояние 51 см, поле зрения 30 Х 5°, фокальная поверхность - сферическая.

> **The Baker Nunn camera (USA)** was the first large satellite tracking camera (created in 1956-1957 rr.). It has a three-axis mount (Fig. 34) and can track the movement of a satellite in an arc of a great circle at speeds from 0 to 7000 "per second. The optical system of the camera can be attributed to a modified Schmidt system (Fig. 35). The diameter of the active opening is 51 cm, focal length 51 cm, field of view 30 X 5 °, focal surface - spherical.

[image]

[image]

> На начальном этапе эксплуатации камеры для временной привязки применялись кварцевые часы Нормана, замененные в 1965-1966 гг. атомными, что позволило обеспечивать точность в 0,0001 с.  Камера может работать в разных режимах, выбор которых зависит от яркости и скорости движения спутника. Систематические обширные наблюдения, выполненные на 12 станциях камерами Бейкера-Наина, послужили ученым SAO для вывода геодезических параметров «Стандартной Земли 1966».

> At the initial stage of the operation of the camera, a Norman quartz clock was used for time reference, replaced in 1965-1966. atomic, which made it possible to provide an accuracy of 0.0001 s. The camera can operate in different modes, the choice of which depends on the brightness and speed of the satellite. Systematic extensive observations made at 12 stations with Baker Nunn cameras served the SAO scientists to derive the Geodetic Parameters for a 1966 Smithsonian Institution Standard Earth.

[image]

> **Камера SBG (Satellitenbeobachtungsgerat, ГДР)** изготавливается фирмой К. Цейсс, Йена. Конструктор камеры М.Штейнбах. Камера имеет четырехосную монтировку (рис. 36). Две оси образуют обычную азимутальную установку и позволяют направлять в полюс орбиты спутников третью ось. Наличие четвертой оси дает возможность отслеживать движение спутника по малому кругу, так как камера может отклоняться от перпендикуляра к третьей оси. Оптическая система камеры является системой Шмидта (рис. 37). Диаметр входного отверстия 425 мм, фокусное расстояние 760 мм, диаметр коррекционной пластинки 150 мм.

> **The SBG (Satellitenbeobachtungsgerat, GDR**) camera is manufactured by C. Zeiss, Jena. Camera constructor M. Steinbach. The camera has a four-axis mount (fig. 36). The two axes form the usual azimuth setting and allow the third axis to be directed to the pole of the satellite orbit. The presence of the fourth axis makes it possible to track the movement of the satellite in a small circle, since the camera can deviate from the perpendicular to the third axis. The optical system of the camera is the Schmidt system (Fig. 37). The diameter of the entrance hole is 425 mm, the focal length is 760 mm, the diameter of the correction plate is 150 mm.

[image]

> **Камера «Антарес» (Франция)** создана в 1967 г. по проекту П. Мюллера. Монтировка камеры
> экваториальная. Камера и гиды установлены на платформе, которая может вращаться вокруг
> третьей оси со скоростью от 2 до 7000" в сек. Можно наклонять ось камеры от перпендикуляра к третьей оси на угол до 6°. Объектив камеры шестилинзовый, его диаметр 300 мм, фокусное расстояние 900 мм . Имеется обтюратор, который прерывает следы спутника и звезд и обеспечивает регистрацию времени наблюдений до 0,0001 сек.  Размер кадра 18 Х l8 см (11 X l0 грд ). При работе неподвижной камерой получались изображения спутников до 5,5m звездной величины. В режиме слежения камера обеспечивала наблюдения спутников Diademe, и имеющих 9-звездную величину.

> **The camera "Antares" (France)** was created in 1967 according to the project of P. Müller. The camera mount is equatorial. The camera and the guides are mounted on a platform that can rotate around the third axis at a speed of 2 to 7000" per second. You can tilt the camera axis from perpendicular to the third axis at an angle of up to 6°. The camera lens has six lenses, its diameter is 300 mm, and the focal length is 900 mm. There is an obturator that interrupts the traces of the satellite and stars and provides registration of observation times up to 0.0001 sec. Frame size 18 X l8 cm (11° X 11° ). When working with a stationary camera, images of satellites up to 5.5m magnitude were obtained. in tracking mode, the camera provided observations of the Diademe satellites, and having 9-magnitude.